# prove $\int_a^\infty xf(x) \, dx \ge\int_a^\infty af(x) \, dx\,, \quad a>0, \, f\ge0$

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, inequality

Studying a proof of Markov's inequality on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality#Proof_in_the_language_of_probability_theory) and I'm stuck at this part:

> $$\int_a^\infty xf(x) \, dx \ge\int_a^\infty af(x) \, dx\,, \quad  a>0, \, f\ge0$$

How do I convince myself that this is satisfied? I mean is $xf(x) \geq af(x)\,,\forall x\geq a$?

Comment: If $f(x) \ge 0$ and $x \ge a > 0$, then $x f(x) \ge a f(x)$.

Comment: Haha, you are correct. I was so fucking close!

Comment: Thank you though

Comment: Well, $f=0$ and $a=-1$ works too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $$\int\limits_a^{+\infty}(x-a)f(x)dx\geq0.$$